# CryptoJS: Is this not a Base64 hash?

Tags: javascript, encryption, base64, cryptojs

people of Earth. I'm tried of spinning my wheels so I turn this over to you. I'm trying to encode a hash to Base64 with the CryptoJS library to output an OAuth1.0a signature. I don't think it's working and I don't know enough about about encryption to know if I'm doing this right.

```
const home = window.location.origin;
const consumerKey = 'ck_2ec6ba5a5f3328e63d340493e56ebd737fb26314';
const consumerSecret = 'cs_eb9545b9707a7ffcd3b40a27ad7f79cc2eee8326';

const oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: { key: consumerKey, secret: consumerSecret },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function(base_string, key) {

        return CryptoJS
            .HmacSHA1(base_string, key)
            .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);    
    },
});

const request_data = {
    url: home + '/wp-json/gf/v2/entries/1',
    method: 'GET'
}

const superSecretStuff = oauth.authorize(request_data, oauth.consumer);
```

The keys are all local API keys so I don't care if you guys see them. The above code outputs **971898495f2f781e94d74700c1cc75659ef627a0** for the signature. The endpoint is expecting a base64 encoded has, and I'm pretty sure that's not base64. If someone could point out what I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it.

Edit: Postman is telling me that the API is expecting a hash like this: **tvaq9gvOSBsdgLvKngU5gSZz7U4=**

Comment: `971898495f2f781e94d74700c1cc75659ef627a0` are all hexidecimal digits, so, unlikely to be base64 (though of course the string contains only valid base64 characters - but still very unlikely that it is base64)

Comment: what lib is OAuth? its not native. the string is a sha1 hash.. `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)` seems like its not working, to produce that string your code might look like just `.toString()`

Comment: try `hash_function: (base_string, key) => CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key)`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. The above code returns on my machine (after definition of a value for `home`) for `superSecretStuff.oauth_signature` a Base64 encoded string (28 bytes), which is after decoding 20 bytes large (corresponding to the `SHA1` length), so exactly as expected. You can run the code from `https://pastebin.com/xGWdfZvF` at `https://repl.it/languages/nodejs`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the post to include how I was factoring the home variable.

Comment: I didn't check the whole code, but I used this call `CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(base_string, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);` before and got the expected result. So I also wonder what might have went wrong. Can you still reproduce the problem?